# Error while deploying contract

Tags: truffle, ether, ropsten

While deploying contract to ropsten tesnet (truffle migrate --network ropsten) I am getting an error:

```
insufficient funds for gas * price + value

  ropsten: {
      network_id: 3,
      host: "localhost",
      port:  8545,
      gas:   4698712,
      gasPrice:   65000000000,
      from: '14e6b19304fb3c98a73acea5f80d2c056ee5c09f'

    }
```

I checked eth.syncing, it was initially false. But after some times it shows something like this:

```
 eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3733045,
  highestBlock: 3737770,
  knownStates: 46235540,
  pulledStates: 46235540,
  startingBlock: 3732532
}
```

How can I fix the error and solve the syncing issue. The syncing has not been completed since 7 days.

Comment: For faster syncing : Be sure that you have SSD and i recommend you to use Parity instead of Geth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, your node is slightly out of sync, by about 5000 blocks or so,

For another, 0x14e6b19304fb3c98a73acea5f80d2c056ee5c09f has no ropsten ether in it, so you would be unable to deploy even with a synced node.

Try using the [faucet](http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001) to get some testnet ether and trying again (you will have to wait until your node has synced up to the block containing the tx that gives you ether).

Comment: Not much you can usually do, beyond buying an SSD if you're using an HDD. Just wait it out, ropsten syncs don't take very long, and you're almost done.

Comment: Thanks. I got an Ether from faucet. The problem was that metamask could not import account using JSON. So, I extracted the private key through myetherwaller.com and imported it in metamask. Now its shows the ether balance and account info correctly on metamask. I was able to deploy contract successfully after sync was completed. Thanks mate!

Comment: One more question, what do you mean by ropsten ether ? Ether means ether and I think it can be used in any network, isn't it ? Ofcourse its a fake ether though.

Comment: It's the same as regular ether, but since they are two separate chains, you need to get some for the correct chain.